# regex with multiple conditional groups in lookahead that must also be captured in match

Tags: python, regex

I which to match 4 patterns in a string, 3 of which are optional

strings can look as follows:

```
form1 = "N-e-1-[(5E)-5,6-e]-4 c"
form2 = "#3,4# N-e-1-[(5E)-5,6-e]-4 c <5,6,7>"
form3 = "#1,2,3# {N-e-1-[(5E)-5,6-e]-4 c} (#4,5# comments <6,7>) <8,9,10>"
```

and i want to match:

```
assert pattern.match(form1).groups() == (None, 'N-e-1-[(5E)-5,6-e]-4 c', None, None)
assert pattern.match(form2).groups() == ('3,4', 'N-e-1-[(5E)-5,6-e]-4 c', None, '5,6,7')
assert pattern.match(form3).groups() == ('1,2,3', 'N-e-1-[(5E)-5,6-e]-4 c', '#4,5# comments <6,7>', '8,9,10')
```

but I'm not quite getting there. This is what I have so far:

```
# match any digits, comma or space separated, enclosed by "#", at the start of the line
optional_first_part = r'^#?([,\d\s]+)?#?' 
# match anything up to the start of an optional third or fourth part
second_part = r'(.*?)(?:<\d+|\(#|$)'
# match anything between "(#X" and "X>)", where X are integers
optional_third_part = r'\(?(#\d+.*\d+\>)?\)?'
# match any digits, comma or space separated, enclosed by "<" and ">", at the end of the line
optional_fourth_part = r'<?([,\d\s]+)?>?$'
# compile pattern
pattern = re.compile(r'{0}{1}{2}{3}'.format(optional_first_part, second_part, 
                                            optional_third_part, optional_fourth_part))
```

and what I now get:

```
pattern.match(form1).groups()
>>> (None, 'N - e - 1 - [(5E) - 5, 6 - e] - 4c', None, None)
pattern.match(form2).groups()
>>> ('3,4', ' N-e-1-[(5E)-5,6-e]-4 c ', None, ',6,7')  # unwanted white spaces, losing start of the fourth part
pattern.match(form3).groups()
>>> ('1,2,3', ' {N-e-1-[(5E)-5,6-e]-4 c} (#4,5# comments <6,7>) ', None, '9,10')  # completely horrible
```

part of the issue is the lookahead: since I match "<\d+" there, the optional fourth part actually doesn't match it. Somehow I need to be able to capture it again in fourth part

In the last example i don't seem able to non-greedily match up to the occurrence of "(#\d+" in the second_part, and thus the third_part is not used

any suggestions?

Comment: Try to change `(.*?)(?:<\d+|\(#|$)` to `(.*?)(?=<\d+|\((?:#|$))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?:#(.*?)#)?\s*\{?(.*?)\}?\s*(?:\((#.*?)\))*\s*(?:<(\d.*?)>)*$
```

[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/ETbK93/1)

Comment: This matches `"N-e-1-[(5E)-5,6-e]-4 c<5,6"`, which I assume is not wanted and even for valid strings it only confirms the entire string is a match, as opposed to separating the string into components, such as `('3,4', ' N-e-1-[(5E)-5,6-e]-4 c ', None, ',6,7')`, as required by the question.

Comment: It parses, not validates, strings of very specific format into 4 groups, because it was asked in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regular expression:

```
/^(?:#(\d+(?:,\d+)*)#)? *([^<]+?) *(?:\(([^()]*)\))? *(?:<(\d+(?:,\d+)*)>)?$/
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/ifR7I8/5/)

We can write it in *free spacing mode* to make it self-documenting:

```
/
^             # match beginning of line
(?:           # begin non-capture group
  #           # match '#'
  (           # begin capture group 1
    \d+       # match 1+ digits  
    (?:,\d+)* # match a comma then 1+ digits in non-capture
              # group, executed 0+ times (*)
  )           # end capture group #1
  #           # match '#'
)?            # end non-capture group and make it optional

\ *           # match 0+ spaces
(.+?)         # match any char 1+ times (+), non-greedily
              # in capture group 2 (not optional)

\ *           # match 0+ spaces
(?:           # begin non-capture group
  \(          # match '('
  ([^()]*)    # match 0+ (*) chars other than '(' and
              # ')' in capture group 3 
  \)          # match ')'       
)?            # end non-capture group and make it optional

\ *           # match 0+ spaces
(?:           # begin non-capture group
  <           # match '<'
  (           # begin capture group 4 
    \d+       # match 1+ digits
    (?:,\d+)* # match a comma then 1+ digits in non-
              # capture group, 0+ times
  )           # end capture group 4
  >           # match '>'
)?            # end non-capture group and make it optional
$             # match end of line
/x            # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

Comment: This regex does not produce the desired output, it captures the group delimiters together with the group content.

Comment: Thanks, @Alex. I missed that. Will repair.

Comment: BTW, this regex matches any string, because it is basically a `.*` with some optional parts. Mine regex does the same, thats why I wrote about parsing, not validating.

Comment: This regex makes some additional assumptions about the structure of the string and because of that is about 15% more effective. It is also well-documented. Upvoting.